# Smarter way to build this list of all possible numbers

Tags: python, list, numpy

I must build a list of 3x2 value combinations with all possible values between 0.0 and 1.0 by the step size given (for now it’s 1/3).

The output should be `[ [[v1, v2], [v3, v4], [v5, v6]], ... ]` where every v is a value between 0.0 and 1.0, e.g.:

```
[ [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]],
[[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.33]],
[[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.66]],
[[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0]],
[[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.33, 0.0]],
[[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.33, 0.33]],
...,
[[1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0]] ]
```

So far I have:

```
step = 1.0/3.0
lexica = []
for num1 in numpy.arange(0.0, 1.0, step):
    for num2 in numpy.arange(0.0, 1.0, step):
        for num3 in numpy.arange(0.0, 1.0, step):
            for num4 in numpy.arange(0.0, 1.0, step):
                for num5 in numpy.arange(0.0, 1.0, step):
                    for num6 in numpy.arange(0.0, 1.0, step):
                        lexica.append([[num1, num2],[num3, num4],[num5, num6]])
```

This doesn't get 1.0 for the highest value and knowing Python there’s got to be a better way of writing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `numpy.mgrid` and manipulate it to give you the output you want

```
np.mgrid[0:1:step, 0:1:step, 0:1:step, 0:1:step, 0:1:step, 0:1:step].T.reshape(-1, 3, 2)
```

**EDIT:**

A bit more extensible method that fixes the endpoints:

```
def myMesh(nSteps, shape = (3, 2)):
    c = np.prod(shape)
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, nSteps + 1)
    return np.array(np.meshgrid(*(x,)*c)).T.reshape((-1, ) + shape)

myMesh(3)

array([[[ 0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ]],

       [[ 0.        ,  0.33333333],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ]],

       [[ 0.        ,  0.66666667],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ]],

       ..., 
       [[ 1.        ,  0.33333333],
        [ 1.        ,  1.        ],
        [ 1.        ,  1.        ]],

       [[ 1.        ,  0.66666667],
        [ 1.        ,  1.        ],
        [ 1.        ,  1.        ]],

       [[ 1.        ,  1.        ],
        [ 1.        ,  1.        ],
        [ 1.        ,  1.        ]]])
```

Comment: very nice! although you have to increase the upper limit; `0.99...` should be included in the result.

Comment: It's included on my machine.  What is your `step` value?

Comment: Nice, but the solution is not scalable if the dimensions are variable (`NxM` output instead of `3x2`).

Comment: ups. sorry in that case. used `step = 1/3`. but probably `step = 0.33` is what OP wants (?).

Comment: Yeah I was just using `step=.33`, if you do `step=1./3.` it doesn't work inclusively (because `.999.....==1`).

Comment: @Horseshaq, if you like the answer please click the check

Comment: @Horseshaq But what do you do if, at some later point, you need to generate for example `10x5` combinations? Are you going to copy & paste `0:1:step` 50 times? Also note that, as Daniel F mentioned, this solution doesn't work with arbitrary step sizes, `numpy.linspace` is suited much better for that kind of tasks.

Comment: Im sorry, this is brillant but it seems Ive misinterpreted my task. Is it possible to change the values to 0.0, 0.33, 0.66, 1.0?

Comment: @a_guest The format of this task will never change, only the step size

Comment: @Horseshaq See if something like `np.array(np.meshgrid(*([np.linspace(0,1,4)]*6))).T.reshape(-1,3,2)` works for you. If you have `50` such loops, simply edit `6` to `50`.

Comment: @Horseshaq Well that doesn't improve the solution. What if your initial task were to generate `10x5` combinations? Take a look at my answer below, it works for arbitrary dimensions and arbitrary step sizes.

Comment: @DanielF Checking the size of your array returns `24576` however the result should be `(4**2)**3 = 4096` if permutations are allowed. So something seems to be wrong.

Comment: It just so happens `4096 * 6 = 24576`.  Every permutation has 6 elements

Comment: @Divakar This gives "invalid character in identifier" error

Comment: The myMesh function seems to be the best of the solutions I've tried. It gives what I want and works with the following functions the result must go through. Thank you

Comment: @DanielF Ah right, I checked `.size` instead of `len`. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

this is what you could do without numpy:

```
from itertools import product

ret = []
for a, b, c, d, e, f in product(range(4), repeat=6):
    ret.append([[a/3, b/3], [c/3, d/3], [e/3, f/3]])
```

or even as a list comprehension:

```
ret = [[[a/3, b/3], [c/3, d/3], [e/3, f/3]] 
       for a, b, c, d, e, f in product(range(4), repeat=6)]
```

Comment: This solutions works, however is not scalable for variable dimensions. Also using `numpy.linspace` is much more appropriate for generating the initial array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) in order to accomplish that task:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as cwr
>>> cwr(cwr(numpy.linspace(0, 1, 4), 2), 3)
```

`cwr(numpy.linspace(0, 1, 4), 2)` creates all possible combinations of length 2 from the elements of `numpy.linspace(0, 1, 4)` (which are `0, 1/3, 2/3, 1`). The outer call `cwr(..., 3)` then creates all possible length 3 tuples from the previous 2-tuples, resulting in your 3x2 elements.

Comment: This works but is there a dynamic way to get the number of elements of the 'list' ? Or must I formulate this elsewhere based on the step size.
This is needed later in the task

Comment: @Horseshaq I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. `numpy.linspace(0, 1, 4)` is what you start from, you can also change it to `numpy.arange(0, 1, 0.33)` if you like. The result is an iterator which you can cast to a list: `list(cwr(...))`. Note that this approach doesn't contain permutations yet (they can be added however, if required).